# Show files only (not folders) in a Office.FileDialog window?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I have a procedure using the `Office.FileDialog` object that goes to a remote folder, sets a `FileDialog.Filter` to search for a specific file in that folder (i.e., `.Filter = "\\PATH\MYFILE*.pdf"`), and then uses `FileDialog.Show` to display a window containing only that target file. When the window is displayed, it contains not only my target file but also all of the sub-folders in the target folder. How can I display only the files, and not the sub-folders?

Answer (score 2):

As filtering applies only to files, and there's nothing of the kind in `fileDialogType` - I don't think what you're asking for is possible in VBA.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will show only .pdf Files in the FileDialog. Just Add the specific path to the folder you want to open the FileDialog to in the quotations after ChDir "YourFile_Path".

```
Dim myFile As String
ChDir "C:\Users\Documents"
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Import pdf File", FileFilter:="Pdf Files *.pdf (*.pdf),")
```